# How mature is apache sshd (MINA)?

Tags: java, apache, ssh

Has anyone ever used [apache sshd](http://mina.apache.org/sshd/index.html) (based on Apache MINA)?

I would like to get some user input.

- Is it mature?
- Does it have (annoying) bugs?
- How is the API?
- Can useful documentation/tutorials be
  found?
- etc.

Thanks all for your feedback.

Comment: for those who think this is a bad question and have down voted it, a comment as to why, would be helpful...

Comment: certainly someone in the world has used it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'll explain: your question isn't concrete. You are not asking "I have this and this problem" or "Can MINA be used for this".

Comment: @Bozho: but my point was to get any feedback. The library seems new and any feedback would help me decide whether to opt for this or some other more mature implementation...

Comment: then ask the question that way "is it mature", "does it have bugs", etc.

Comment: @Bozho: hope the edit helps ;-)

Comment: Seriously, what would be a bounty worth answer here? One that says yes or one that says no?

Comment: @random: under he rules for dispensing out bounties (check the faq) if an answer does not have at least 2 upvotes it will not get the points, in case I choose no answer. And I have no intention of choosing either the "yes" or the "no"

Comment: Sorry all those who had genuinely been interested in this question, I had not managed to get better answers... Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

We are using it for command line OM interface to our spring server apps. We are happy. We connected it to a groovy shell, and defined our own OM commands there.